# CatapultC reverse bit order

Tags: hardware, reverse, fpga

Does anyone know how to convert between little and big endians in CataputC?
Part of the design, I am working on, needs to use litle endian and rest uses big endian.
I am searching for something equivalent to "downto" "to" keywords in vhdl.

Answer (score 1):

After a while I realized that you simply have to reverse it in loop and Catapult synthesis tool accepts it as signal reverse. So I made myself a useful template.

```
template<int W> ac_int<W> reversed(ac_int<W> in) {
    ac_int<W> out;
    for (int i = 0; i < W; i++)
        out[i] = in[W - i - 1];

    return out;
}
```